# angular, route, updating scope with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have a problem with angular route. In my single page app, I have a routeProvider with routes defined. One route has template where there is ng-click defined and the corresponding controller has the logic. The method in the logic is called, but nothing gets rendered to UI, in fact the whole ng-view part is wiped clean.

Any examples, where there is logic in the template controller?

Comment: Could you please provide some code? It's hard to guess what is the problem by your explanation alone.

Comment: Can't put the code here, since its related to  customer project. I'll try to make a simplified example of it. Any ways how to track what happens, there are no errors in console?

Comment: There is angular batarang https://github.com/spalger/angularjs-batarang/blob/master/README.md. With it you should be able to inspect scope